# java.io.WindowsFileSystem?

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

`java.io.File` uses a native method (`System.getFileSystem()`) to get the native file system.

I noticed that there is no class `java.io.WindowsFileSystem` that inherits from `java.io.FileSystem` but there is an inheriting class called `java.io.UnixFileSystem` as of version 6-b14. Why could this be implemented like so?

I would also be grateful if someone could mention where I could find the `System.getFileSystem()` native counterpart at OpenJDK or somewhere online.

Comment: See http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/io/FileSystem.html - it lists Unix (?), WinNT (NTFS), and Win32 (Fat32) implementations as subclasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle JVM for Unix doesn't have the windows class, and the Windows version doesn't have the Unix class.  The OpenJDK has both even though you cannot use both of them on the same machine whether you have windows or unix.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused though. I was looking at grepcode.com for OpenJDK 6-b14. On 7-b147, The Win32FileSystem class is there. Probably, grepcode is incomplete or 6-b14 has a different implementation?

Comment: @bimboxX There was a number of odd things about OpenJDK 6, I would look at 7 as a better example of how it should have been done.